# decreasing video resolution using ffmpeg increases file size

Tags: ffmpeg

I try to decrease video resolution using ffmpeg by,

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -loglevel panic -i "input.mp4" -vf "scale=-1:256" -q:v 1 -c:a copy -threads 1 "output.mp4"
```

But the video file size is increased. 
The original height is larger than 256.
Why the file size is increased though the resolution is decreased?

Answer (score 1):

Because bitrate and resolution are independent variables. -q:v 1 basically means to use as many bits as necessary to keep the video nearly identical to the (scaled) input.

Comment: Thanks. Then is there any way that I can save the output with the same quality(?) as the input so that the file size become around proportional to the resolution?

Comment: You first need to define what “proportional to the resolution” means. There is no such concept in video encoding. An all black image would only take a few bytes to encode. While white noise is barely compressible without a lot of signal loss. You can target a quantization, or you can target file size, you need to pick one and set the correct parameters.